# Position of legend in matplot with secondary y-axis (python)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I try to create a plot in python with matplotlib consisting of two plots and one with a secondary y-axis. The first is a scatter and the second a line plot.
Now, I want to move the legend to somewhere else but whenever I use `ax.legend()` only the label of the first axis appears but the second vanishes.

```
import pandas as pd

# the data:
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': {0: '2021-01-01 18:00:00', 1: '2021-01-02 20:00:00', 2: '2021-01-03 19:00:00', 3: '2021-01-04 17:00:00', 4: '2021-01-05 18:00:00', 5: '2021-01-06 18:00:00', 6: '2021-01-07 21:00:00', 7: '2021-01-08 16:00:00'},
     'Value A': {0: 107.6, 1: 86.0, 2: 17.3, 3: 56.8, 4: 30.0, 5: 78.3, 6: 110.1, 7: 59.0},
     'Value B': {0: 17.7, 1: 14.1, 2: 77.4, 3: 4.9, 4: 44.4, 5: 28.3, 6: 22.9, 7: 83.2},
     'Value C': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.5, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.6, 4: 0.9, 5: np.nan, 6: 0.1, 7: 0.8},
     'Value D': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.7, 2: 0.1, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.4, 5: 0.8, 6: 0.8, 7: 0.8},
     'Flag': {0: 1, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: 1, 7: np.nan}})
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])

# plot the flagged points as dots
data_flag = data[data["Flag"] == True]
ax = data_flag.plot.scatter(x="Date",
                            y="Value A",
                            c="black",
                            label="Outlier")

# plot the series as lines
ax = data.plot(x="Date",
               y=["Value A",
                  "Value B",
                  "Value C",
                  "Value D"
                  ],
               secondary_y=["Value C", "Value D"],
               ax=ax
               )

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05))

plt.show()
```

The output looks like this with missing labels in the legend for the secondary axis

[image]

Without the `ax.legend()`, the labels for "Value C" and "Value D" are part of the legend.

What is the best way to move all labels at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach (using your provided data):

```py
# plot the flagged points as dots
data_flag = data[data["Flag"] == True]
ax = data_flag.plot.scatter(x="Date",
                            y="Value A",
                            c="black",
                            label="Outlier")

# plot the series as lines
ax = data.plot(x="Date",
               y=["Value A",
                  "Value B",
               ],
               secondary_y=False,
               ax=ax
               )

ax2 = data.plot(x="Date",
               y=["Value C",
                  "Value D"
                  ],
               secondary_y=True,
               ax=ax
               )

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.1), loc="upper left")
ax.set_ylabel("Value A, Value B")
ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 0.85), loc="upper left")
ax2.set_ylabel("Value C, Value D")


plt.show()
```

Three plots are generated, one for the flagged outlier, one for `Value A, Value B` and the last one with a secondary y-axis for the `Value C, Value D`. This looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That seems to solve the issue. Having two legends and adjusting their position manually is acceptable as I have to find the best position anyway.